# Show context sensitive keyboard upper case or lower case characters on the iPad

Tags: keyboard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to configure the keyboard on an iPad](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/49886/is-there-a-way-to-configure-the-keyboard-on-an-ipad)

My Windows Phone's keyboard displays the characters on it depending on the context, i.e, if I am currently typing lower case characters the keyboard overlay is lowercase and ditto for upper case.

I just got myself a new iPad yesterday and found that the keyboard is always stuck on uppercase. I mean when I type it works fine but the overlay is always uppercase. Anyway to change this?

Comment: What os level is on your iPhone? That seems odd behavior

Comment: @bmike: You know I could have sworn thats how my iphone worked but I checked and realized that how my Windows Phone works!

Comment: The question still holds though.

Comment: Hmm... My iPhone overlay is always on upper case.

Comment: There is no way to change the way the iOS keyboard works, which is always uppercase.

Comment: Seems like the same question as http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/49886/is-there-a-way-to-configure-the-keyboard-on-an-ipad

Comment: No way to change that without jail breaking.

Comment: @bmike It's perfectly normal. The keys themselves always display uppercase, no matter what case they're actually typing. Just like a hardware keyboard!